# How to stop the resizable property of an element in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize

I'm using jQuery UI library to provide some UI functionalities to the DOM elements.

I have a div that can be resized when the client selects a custom dimension option, but I also have another mode that resizes the div with a fixed dimensions and the client cannot resize the div.

My code of the "custom dimensions" is similar to this:

```
$("#element").resizable ({
    aspectRatio: 4/3,
    minWidth: 320,
    minHeight: 240,
    maxWidth: 640,
    maxHeight: 480
});
```

But now I need to stop the resizing event. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**By disabling**

The plugin provides a "disable" method that you can call like this:

```
$("#element").resizable('disable');
```

The *problem* is that it adds a class "ui-state-disabled" to the resizable element giving it a visual disabled state. If you don't want that, you override the style or remove the added class like this:

```
$("#element").resizable('disable').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

---

**By destroying**

Another way to do this is to "destroy" the plugin from the element when you don't want it to be resizable:

```
$("#element").resizable('destroy');
```

You can then re-apply your resizable if you'd like to re-enable the effect again

Answer (score 4):

Call the [`destroy`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#method-destroy) or [`disable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#method-disable) methods, e.g.:

```
$("#element").resizable('disable');
```

If you use `disable`, you can use [`enable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#method-enable) again later, but the default action also dims the element a bit which you may not want.

Completely gratuitous live demos: [enable/disable](http://jsbin.com/odufop) | [destroy/recreate](http://jsbin.com/odufop/2)